# Counting spanning trees with 5 vertices

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I am trying to count the number of spanning trees for 5 vertices. I am trying to look at the degree of the unlabeled graph.

So for the unlabeled graph with a node of degree 4, there should be ${5 \choose 1}$ ways

for the graph with three vertices of degree 2, there should be $\frac{5!}{2}$ ways

but I have no idea how to count the last unlabeled graph that has a vertex degree of 3 and a vertex degree of 2.

I know that from Cayley's formula the last graph has to have $60$ ways but I want to know how to get to the number $60$.

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The vertex labeled $5$ can be chosen in $5$ ways.

The vertex labeled $4$ can be chosen in $4$ ways.

The vertex labeled $3$ can be chosen in $3$ ways.

The last two vertices can be swapped and so there is only one way to label them.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you get that there are 3 and 4 ways for the vertices 3, and 4?

Comment: Once you have chosen the first vertex (in $5$ possible ways), it must be joined to one of the $4$ remaining verices & then this vertex must be joined to one of the remaining $3$ vertices & finally this vertex is joined to the remaining $2$.

Comment: ok, I am seeing it now thank you for the help.